# Average daily peak hours in a week with SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I'm trying to list the weekly average of customers in different restaurants in their daily peak hours, for example:

Week | Day | Hour  | Rest | Custom
20   | Mon | 08-12 | KFC  | 15
20   | Mon | 12-16 | KFC  | 10
20   | Mon | 16-20 | KFC  | 8
20   | Tue | 08-12 | KFC  | 20
20   | Tue | 12-16 | KFC  | 11
20   | Tue | 16-20 | KFC  | 9
20   | Mon | 08-12 | MCD  | 13
20   | Mon | 12-16 | MCD  | 14
20   | Mon | 16-20 | MCD  | 19
20   | Tue | 08-12 | MCD  | 31
20   | Tue | 12-16 | MCD  | 20
20   | Tue | 16-20 | MCD  | 22
20   | Mon | 08-12 | PHT  | 15
20   | Mon | 12-16 | PHT  | 12
20   | Mon | 16-20 | PHT  | 11
20   | Tue | 08-12 | PHT  | 08
20   | Tue | 12-16 | PHT  | 07
20   | Tue | 16-20 | PHT  | 14

The desired result should be:

WeeK | Rest | Custom
20   | KFC  | 17.5
20   | MCD  | 25
20   | PHT  | 14.5

Is it possible to do it in one line of SQL?

Comment: Please define "daily peak hours".

Answer (score 0):

This is really two steps. Get the maximum people per day per restaurant and then average that per week:

```
select week, rest, sum(maxc)
from (select Week, Day, Rest, max(Custom) as maxc
      from t
      group by Week, Day, Rest
     ) wdr
group by week, rest;
```